# Is OWIN fully supported by all the .NET Frameworks?

Tags: asp.net, .net, server, .net-core, owin

My problem is that I'm making a little documentation about the full support of all OWIN's specifications in .NET Framework and unfortunately I don't find a lot of informations about this.

At this moment, I know that .NET Core is based on the OWIN specifications so it's fully supported.

For the .NET Framework I just know that there is project named Katana but does it mean that all OWIN standards can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OWIN is a specification. Its a set of instructions that describes “how” something should work..

Katana is Microsoft's OWIN implementation and also includes some middleware components for security/authentication, serving static files, and a few other things.

Kestrel is Microsoft's cross-platform development web server that can be used with ASP.NET 5. and NetCore

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! So before ASP .NET 5 all the OWIN specifications were not fully supported ?

Comment: @Gwynbleidd - the [History of ASP.Net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Versions) is hardly a secret. Of course, the really old versions didn't support it because OWIN didn't exist at the time.

Comment: I think Katana implemented the OWIN specs, but it was recommended to link it with IIS if you wanted the whole “Microsoft” stack - extra security etc.. So it was a full OWIN implementation, but that doesnt rival the features of IIS on its own..